# Echo Arrays in Array between [ ]

Tags: php

I have a site using json script to show player connected to the server and i want to print it on the website that we use for the community.

So the server print this info with the json script:

```
[{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":41,"identifiers":"steam:1100001XXXXX","license:d25c32a7dXXXX"],"name":"Juan Carlos","ping":69}]
```

My issue is when I want to echo the steamID that return me ARRAY instead of
"1100001XXXXX"

My code:

```
 foreach($data as $object):?>

       <tr>
            <td><?php echo $object->{'id'}?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object->{'name'}?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object->{'identifiers'}?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object->{'ping'}?></td>
```

Have you got any ideas for helping me?

Comment: `i am unable to see steamID` in your given array input

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid JSON. From the error message, it sounds like the identifiers key actually points to an array.

Comment: If you look you have a closing brace in the middle of your json to start. It's invalid.

Comment: Post your real json data, not your own created-one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, editing now that you supplied valid data. Look here:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":27,"identifiers":["steam:11000011190e09d","license:bc7e7c16b4c762c0c2a67160ec68db4559b4c03b"],"name":"Nicro Scaro","ping":73},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":25,"identifiers":["steam:110000105b1c9bd","license:ba7eb97475632e190bb366d61f97411e2006132e"],"name":"Paolo Gillet","ping":25},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":20,"identifiers":["steam:110000101facefb","license:425097d969f377ca9b916412893f5c55b9a1c282"],"name":"Genaro Savastano","ping":33},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":29,"identifiers":["steam:1100001083dff7d","license:6610bb9fd154d505d29f29ca3319473e4da34ee0"],"name":"Steven Stifler","ping":55},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":21,"identifiers":["steam:1100001041335a7","license:f28c54417b5487064076061e5078fb784ee66912"],"name":"Samuel Vegas","ping":41},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":26,"identifiers":["steam:110000105f5b25c","license:f6cf282a0a543d923f4c81cab9c7d157343f81e6"],"name":"Thomas Shelby","ping":36},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":23,"identifiers":["steam:110000117812da2","license:50dd53775bccb021c5bbb6a142c5961d2f07a43d"],"name":"Thomas Delome","ping":40},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":31,"identifiers":["steam:110000104b8adb2","license:65f99a4c62163d6e7cb002defc55c03854e2a7ac"],"name":"Bobby Sicouleur","ping":29},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":11,"identifiers":["steam:110000104481335","license:cd2b817c6655280c34bd1f41f8ae168804ec7ed2"],"name":"Paolo Garcia","ping":16},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":24,"identifiers":["steam:110000101450e74","license:8139d095f9bf5de832171f07bf60dba5e9665ed3"],"name":"Mohammed Latifi","ping":163},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":28,"identifiers":["steam:1100001097c401b","license:9fdcc12449270e6528bdf19b2edb7eef1ab1011f"],"name":"Marcel Delahé","ping":27},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":30,"identifiers":["steam:11000010285a33f","license:019951830b346c77571d90df9b6a96f580c1358d"],"name":"Gérard Leblanc","ping":30}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row['identifiers'][0]."\n"; 
}
```

Which will echo out all the steam identifiers. `var_dump($row)` to see everything it has.
See the code working here: https://3v4l.org/7UotT

Comment: Not, I can't edit the Json file, I can just show the input.
What I want to echo is the value 1100001XXXXX from the script located on the http://serverurl/players.json

"identifiers"[steam:110000113a1225e","license:d25c32a7d87c3520aefcbb3aaa4605e7160c9ea4"]

Comment: Here an exemple of the input from the server: 
http://188.165.194.201:30120/players.json

Comment: That's valid JSON and NOT what you posted. Ok, hold on

Comment: edited, please mark my answer up now that I edited. :-)

Comment: glad i could help! :-)